# Winlogbeat - CRIT Setup returned an error: yaml: control characters are not allowed

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

I got this error with one of the servers after installation:
CRIT Setup returned an error: yaml: control characters are not allowed

Winlogbeat wasn't changed.

I was able to resolve and thought sharing my solution.

Comment: What version were you running when this occurred?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with winlogbeat:
https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/2313#issuecomment-244211872

I was able to resolve by cleaning the bad cache.
C:\ProgramData\winlogbeat.winlogbeat.yml

Seems like installing a newer version might also work